# Renaming file in setup project in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, file-rename

I have written a WPF/C# desktop application with a standard setup project. When the application is installed, an sqlite database is placed locally on the users file system. Now, I have renamed my app and I want to rename the database as well. I have renamed the database file in the solution explorer (the corresponding file in project folder is automatically renamed) and on the File System tab of the setup project. However, the name of the database under the setup project in the solution explorer is not changed.

I am not sure whether this really matters, Source path and TargetName for the setup project database has the new name and everything seems to work. But i figure it could be confusing for someone else with dirrerent names for the same database, and I worry it could lead to some problem I cant foresee.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can edit it directly from the project file, if i remember correctly its an xml